# Stretching camera preview to full screen in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-camera

I am using this [camera preview](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Camera/Preview/) application for my Android app.

I want the camera preview over the full screen.Hence I used the example from Android APIs to try setting the preview to full screen. This is how I am trying to do it:

```
if (!cameraConfigured) {
    Camera.Parameters parameters=camera.getParameters();
    Camera.Size size = getOptimalPreviewSize(mSupportedPreviewSizes, width, height);
    if (size != null) {
        parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

      camera.setParameters(parameters);
      cameraConfigured=true;
    }
```

I am using relative layout as my layout. My layout settings are follows:

```
<android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/preview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
```

I am still not able to preview my camera over the entire screen. I would like to know how to preview over the entire screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I added the following setting to Android Manifest file

```
<supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
                    android:normalScreens="true"
                    android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
```

I am able to view the camera over full screen.

Comment: Hi, do you have also the problem that in full screen the camera preview image is skewed / stretched in order to fit on the screen? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16727836/camera-display-preview-in-full-screen-does-not-maintain-aspect-ratio-image-i  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im assuming your code is within a class that extends SurfaceView and that you will place the surfaceView inside a FrameLayout that is as large as the display.

What you are not doing in your code is setting your SurfaceView to be the same size as the display which in the following code block is done by getting the layout, and setting the width and height.

I use the following code to stretch to the dimensions of the screen:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    ...

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {

      ...

      final DisplayMetrics dm = this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
      Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
      parameters.setPreviewSize(cameraSize.width, cameraSize.height);
      mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
      //Here you get the SurfaceView layout and subsequently set its width and height
      FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this.getLayoutParams();
      frameParams.width = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;// dm.widthPixels should also work
      frameParams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;//dm.heightPixels should also work
      this.setLayoutParams(frameParams);
      //And we should have things set now...

      ....

    }

    ...
}
```

I hope this helps. The key parts to integrate are between those inner comments

Comment: Hi, do you have also the problem that in full screen the camera preview image is skewed / stretched in order to fit on the screen? stackoverflow.com/questions/16727836/… Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Get dimensions of the screen

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

use this width and height to get preview size.

Answer (score -1):

First, get the display width and height:

```
   int dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();    // dw == display width
   int dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();   // dh == display height
```

Then loop through the supported preview sizes, and pick the largest one where, if
(size.width <= dw && size.height <= dh).  When you hit one where this if statement
fails, use the previous values (you could set something like prevWidth and prevHeight
as a quick/easy way to step back one ... just remember to set each of those AFTER
you test them; after you hit a preview size that's larger than screen size, just
break out of the loop.

Later,
   --jim